# How to access a node inside of a GridPane in java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm dynamically generating a square GridPane with an equal number of columns and rows. I'm populating each index of the GridPane with a Rectangle object. All I need to do is change the color of one of these Rectangle objects at a specific (column,row) index. I see two ways of solving this problem.

1. Retrieve the object and directly change it's color witht the setFill() method.
2. Remove the rectangle at the target index, create a new rectangle, and insert the new one.

If anyone has any ideas on how either of these could be done I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Here's some other methods you can try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534594/generating-an-n-x-n-grid/33535310#33535310 or if you must use a gridpane http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815075/how-to-obtain-the-information-inside-a-gridpane-javafx/33817265#33817265

Answer (score 0):

You could of course store those `Rectangle`s in a `Rectangle[][]` array with the array indices matching the `GridPane` indices, which allows you to easily access the element using the given indices.

You could however also identify the child using the layout parameters of `GridPane`

```
for (Node child : gridPane.getChildren()) {
    Integer r = GridPane.getRowIndex(child);
    Integer c = GridPane.getColumnIndex(child);
    int row = r == null ? 0 : r;
    int column = c == null ? 0 : c;
    if (row == searchRow && column == searchColumn && (child instanceof Rectangle)) {
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) child;

        // do something with rect

        break;
    }
}
```